Google Calendar API v3 - Only send emails to newly added attendees
I am using Google Calendar API v3 for Google Workspace. I need to add attendees to existing events.
I use C# with official Google Calendar library. I have a service account with impersonation.
When I add an attendee, all attendees receive an notification according to SendUpdates request parameter. Apparently the API behaves correctly according to documentation.
But I need to send email only to a newly added attendee, to match UI experience.
var serviceCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json)
    .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events")
    .CreateWithUser("impersonated_user@example.com");

using var calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = serviceCredential,
    ApplicationName = "AppName",
});

var evt = calendarService.Events.Get("<calendar_id>", "<event_id>").Execute();

evt.Attendees.Add(new EventAttendee()
{
    DisplayName = "Firstname Lastname",
    Email = "email@example.com"
});

// with calendarService.Events.Update, it also sends invitation to all attendees
var request = calendarService.Events.Patch(evt, CalendarId, evt.Id);
request.SendUpdates = EventsResource.PatchRequest.SendUpdatesEnum.ExternalOnly;
request.Execute();


Is there a way?

Instead of sending to the calendar event just send email to the new attendee in the Add method.

I understand that you are trying to add attendees and send only email to those, I can see that it was being discussed on Google's Support Public Issue Tracker, it will help you get more direct answers to your question. Here's the link for the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/323087133.

I have 2 workarounds in mind. One is to not send notifications through the patch, and just use the GMAIL API just keep in mind that it will not perfectly replicate the UI version of it. Another one  includes 3 API calls, 1st call will remove all current attendees with no notification, 2nd call will be adding your desired attendees with notification and 3rd is to add all the removed attendees without notification. This are long shots work around I just want to clarify this.

@Babanana Great comments, thanks a lot. If you mind creating an answer from those, I would mark it as accepted answer, since it is a Google Api issue. And your workaround makes perfect sense.

Sending Email only to the Attendees added on the Event
With my research, it is an ongoing discussion on Google's Official Issue Tracker. Here is the link for it: Issue, I would suggest contributing with this thread to have a better chance of getting an answer from it sooner.
Workaround:
1st Suggestion: Instead of sending notifications through Google Calendar API utilize GMAIL API to send email to the added attendees. Note: This part won't perfectly provide replication from UI results however it will be closed enough depending on how you are going to create the email you will send.
2nd Suggestion: Doing 3 API calls from Google Calendar API. 1st Call would be removing all attendees on the Event with no notification. Next is adding attendees with notification. Last is adding removed attendees without notification. This will be as close with the UI's behaviour however depending on the use case you might encounter some sort of runtime issues. Please do keep this in mind.
Suggested Reference:
GMAIL API. (messages.send)
Calendar API (events.update)

Provided Google issue is unfortunately closed as fixed, but it is not fixed. Your 2nd workaround should work though, thank you.
