Google calendar attendees getting unwanted entries
I am creating a meeting in Google calendar using this API:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/test.user1@mydomain.com/events/import?quotaUser=test.user1@mydomain.com&supportsAttachments=True&access_token=ya29.a0AcM612zVZS40w...

(Note that in all example code here, I have changed the email addresses for privacy)
The event is a meeting with an organizer and multiple attendees. This issue I'm having is that while the event gets created OK in the calendar of the user that I am importing to, also, ALL of the attendees also get this event added to their calendar. This is NOT what I want - I just want the event added to the calendar of test.user1, not test.user2.
I've run this code with other customer accounts and have never seen this behavior before, this seems to be something new. The JSON code I'm using is below. Can anybody explain what's going on, and how to correct it?
{
 "summary": "Test Meeting",
 "organizer":  {
    "email": "test.user1@mydomain.com",
    "displayName": "test.user1@mydomain.com",
    "self": true
},
 "iCalUID": "65e1ebe033c1cfdde029312745195c8b-30746",
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2024-10-07T10:30:00-07:00",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
},
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2024-10-07T11:30:00-07:00",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
},
 "recurrence": [
 "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO"
 ],
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": false,
  "overrides": [
  {
  "method": "popup",
  "minutes": 10
   } ]
 },
 "attendees": [
  {
  "email": "test.user2@mydomain.com",
 "resource": false,
 "optional": false,
  "responseStatus": "accepted"
  },
  {
  "email": "test.user1@mydomain.com",
 "resource": false,
 "optional": false,
  "responseStatus": "accepted"
  }
  ],
 "visibility": "default"
}

EDIT: As requested, this question is different from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78821662/google-calendar-api-v3-only-send-emails-to-newly-added-attendees

because that question concerned making a modification to the attendee list of an existing event. This question is about creating a brand new event, and making sure that the calendar of attendees is not updated.
I do have a significant update to this question however.  I have determined that it is the process of modifying instances of the recurring event that causes the attendee calendar's to be updated. I am using the documentation found here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/recurringevents#protocol_1

Modifying the instance works fine, it's just that now, those updates go to the attendees as well. There is no mention of attendees in the JSON data that I submit. If anyone has any insight into this behavior, I'd appreciate it.

This question is similar to: Google Calendar API v3 - Only send emails to newly added attendees. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See edits, as requested.

I do apologize I do have a hard time understanding your overall Objective for the project and what is your current issue. As what I have gathered from your post you want to modify the event but don't want to reflect these changes to your attendees?  If this is the case, I do think that it is a natural workflow from Google Calendar as it should show what is the current status of the event and its details.
